# Azure CDN and caching control show TCP_MISS

Tags: .net, azure, cdn, http-caching, azure-cdn

Why is Azure CDN keep returning and X-Cache of TCP_MISS meaning the data wasn't taken from cache even though there are cache headers involved?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2024 21:17:12 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
Expires: Thu, 21 Mar 2024 21:17:12 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 28 Feb 2023 18:23:02 GMT
Vary: *
X-Exposure-Sport: Other
X-Exposure-Server: EastUS2
Link: <https://test.com/assets/files/png/252419>; rel="canonical"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Powered-By: Exposure
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-azure-ref: 20240320T211711Z-ygn3rsvu7513p5nd82y8vygcu800000003u000000000mtgg
x-fd-int-roxy-purgeid: 0
X-Cache: TCP_MISS
Content-Length: 50876
```